# java swings to display different panel in same frame (java)

Tags: java

the below given is a java class which get invoked on clicking "next" button in first frame .and i send a parameter is i send getContentPane() to this given below program , here ill access the parameter and set its visibality to false , here i use "Back" button to go to previous page dats for ma first frame , but on clicking Back its not showing the previous frame for me , plz help me out with dis

its just a simple program , if i need to take some text input from second frame and again i need to come back to home screen so, how can i achieve this in this program

```
  public class firstframe extends JFrame{

 public firstframe()
 {
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JButton next=new JButton("Next");
    next.setBounds(100,100,100,100);
    getContentPane().add(next);


    next.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev){

            Container c=getContentPane();

        }
         new signup(c);
    }); 
  }
   public static void main(String ar[]){
   firstframe f=new firstframe();
     f.setVisible(true);
    f.setSize(1365,740);
f.show();
```

} 
}

```
public class signup extends JFrame{

    public signup(Container d)
    {
        final Container c=d;
        c.setVisible(false);
        final Container e;
        e=c.getParent();
        e.setLayout(null);
        JButton back=new JButton("Back");
        back.setBounds(100,100,100,100);
        e.add(back);
        e.setVisible(true);


        back.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev){
                e.setVisible(false);
                d.setVisible(true);
            }

        }); 
    }
}//
```

Comment: You should consider posting an SSCCE [http://sscce.org] to help us better understand your problem.

Comment: Your Signup class (capitalize class names) should be a JDialog, rather than a JFrame.  You should also not extend Swing components unless you're going to override a component method.  You should use Swing components in your own classes.

Comment: can u plz help me out i'm an just a beginner , so can u let me knw how can i display again d first frame

Comment: its just a simple program , if i need to take some text input from second frame and again i need to come back to home screen so, how can i achieve this in this program.

Comment: JDialog does not have minimize and maximize buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but your code style is not good. Too many unnecessary assignments which prevents me to understand code meaning and too short variables names.

Look what you do. In `signup()` method you assign `e=c.getParent();` it means `e` is parent component of `c` and `d`. Then in `back` action listener you make `e` unvisible and try to make `d` visible. But so as `e` is parent of `d`, `d` never becomes visible while its parent is unvisible.

Quick fix for this code is change `back` button action listener to

```
back.setVisible(false);
d.setVisible(true);
```

And of course make `back` final

```
final JButton back=new JButton("Back");
```

Comment: thank you, your response was very helpful for me .


once again, thank you :-)